# VR RPG like dialogue system

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

So I'm trying to implement a dialogue like system using Google Carboard VR, and I have been having trouble as to how I would implement this, I tried using [Fungus](http://fungusgames.com) but the dialogue boxes that are showing up are not exactly VR ready. This is how it is showing up:

[image: How the dialog boxes are appearing]

I got references to individual cameras (Left and Right) and setting them as parents to script generated dialogue boxes (duplicated it onto both) as their respective parents. Also, I tried changing their positions to inside each respective lens but still i did not get the result i needed.
Is there a tutorial for Fungus for VR or if someone has worked on something similar. Or is there any other asset (preferably free) that can help me with what I am trying to do? OR maybe a solution through Unity's native UI?

Keep in mind I need a solution for VR not normal rendering.

Comment: `but still i did not get the result i needed` how?

Comment: and the link is broken

Comment: You need a world space canvas for the UI. Go look for pretty much any UI tutorial for VR.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I know about world space canvas, although I may be able to emulate what I want with it, it will be extremely hard to dynamically change all possible conversations with multiple people. That is good for labeling stuff, and in fact I have used that in my application for that purpose

Comment: @Bijan I want to view it wearing a VR headset, and with the dialogue box appearing in  the middle like that, i.e: between the lenses, it wont be visible properly.

Comment: You use a world space canvas and you can "face lock" it by updating its position every frame. Look at the roll-a-ball tutorial on the unity site. Instead of moving the camera every frame to follow the ball you update the location of the canvas to follow the camera direction.